# How do I download all images from a webpage with wget

Tags: linux, command-line, curl, wget

I want to download all images from a webpage but when I type:

```
$ wget -nd -r -P images -A "*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png" "Path/to/url"
```

`wget` not only downloads images from the webpage I want but it also downloads every other image from the website and loops forever. I have to stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

When I change the command to:

```
$ wget -np -nd -r -P images -A "*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png" "Path/to/url"
```

It doesn't download anything at all.

**Note:** When I run either of the two commands, `wget` always prints this message:

> "Removing 'filename' since it should be rejected"

How do I use `wget` to download images from a webpage?

Comment: `man wget` for download options.

Comment: I think you simply want to download the webpage that has the images you're interested in. Then issue a `wget -A "*.jpg, *.jpeg" -i ./the-page-you-downloaded`

Answer (score 1):

try adding the -l<#> switch, where # is the number of pages you want to go down